# OpenVPN based Site-to-Site VPN between Azure on premise server is it secure?

Tags: azure, windows-server-2016, azure-vpn

OpenVPN based Site-to-Site VPN between Azure on premise server is it secure?

We are trying to setup Site to site connection but our firewall doesn't have Ikev2 
So we want to setup the vpn without the need of the firewall. It seems OpenVPN in azure can do the job

Although it uses certificates to authenticate but i'm not sure the security and performance of bypassing the firewall.

I would love to know your input of how to setup and if this route is the best.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

OpenVPN uses tunneling over SSL. So traffic over OpenVPN is encrypted and it is safe to use. As it is using SSL/TLS for Key exchange it is safe to by pass your firewall.